# Issues enabling CORS support for Lambda proxy integrations

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, axios, cors, aws-api-gateway

I have a lambda function which I've exposed through API Gateway. I'm calling the function with axios. I've not enabled cors on the API Gateway with the OPTIONS method because I'm using lambda proxy integration so I'm sending back the response headers in my lambda function. It works on insomnia but on the browser I'm getting the {message: forbidden} and the error below.

```
[Error] Preflight response is not successful
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://xxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/production/user/xxxxxxxxxxxxx due to access control checks.
[Error] Failed to load resource: Preflight response is not successful (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, line 0)
[Error] Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: Network Error
    (anonymous function)
    promiseReactionJob
```

THE AXIOS FUNCTION

```
import axios from "axios";
const baseURL =
  "https://xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/production/";
import * as apiKey from "./apiConfig";

export const getUser = (username) => {
  return axios
    .get(`${baseURL}user/${username}`, {
      headers: {
        "x-api-key": apiKey
      },
    })
    .then(({ data }) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
};
```

THE LAMBDA FUNCTION RETURNS

```
const response = {
     statusCode: 200,
     body: JSON.stringify(data.Item),
headers: {
   "Content-Type": "application/json",
   "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
},
   };
   return response;
```

**EDIT** 
Following suggestions, I enabled CORS on API Gateway which created the OPTIONS method with the following headers and header mappings. The above error of preflight response is gone. Instead I now receive this error below. I'd also like to note Api Key Required is set to false for the OPTIONS method, however when I set it to true I get the above error again.

```
{message: forbidden}
https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/production/user/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 () (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, line 0)
Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: Request failed with status code 403
```

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers : 'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'   
Access-Control-Allow-Methods : 'DELETE,GET,OPTIONS,PATCH'   
Access-Control-Allow-Origin : '*'
```

Comment: PreFlight uses `OPTIONS` method. If you ignored it, this could potentially explain your error.

Comment: @Marcin thank you for replying to my question. I re-enabled CORS on API Gateway with OPTIONS but still received an error? See Edit

Comment: did you attach a policy to your lambda function which allows API Gateway to actually invoke it?

Comment: @tpschmidt No there's no resource policy attached. It does work in insomnia.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up enabling CORS, re-deploying the API Gateway and set all the headers to lambda functions below. It didn't work straight away but after a little while after deploying.

```
const response = {
     statusCode: 200,
     body: JSON.stringify(data.Item),
headers: {
   "Content-Type": "application/json",
   "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
},
   };
   return response;
```